# jquery array to list without comma

Tags: jquery, arrays, push

So i have a list of locations and this is being stored it the following:

```
var locations;
```

When i console.log this i get the following:

```
CA,CH,LA
```

How could i do this so i get a list of the locations and without the commas. I was thinking a foreach loop but this didnt work.

I the achieved outcome would look this this

```
CA
CH
LA
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call `join()` on an array to create a string from each element concatenated together by any character you need.

```
// without commas
console.log(locations.join('')); // = "CACHLA"

// by newline (\n)
console.log(locations.join("\n")); // =
// CA
// CH
// LA
```

Comment: your awesome :D Iv never heard of join before, thanks

Comment: $(".postcode_check").each(function(){
                    if($(this).val() == pre_locations.join("\n")){
                        $(this).prop('checked', true);
                    }
                });

Answer (score 1):

`locations` is an `Array` so, explicitly call `Array.join` on it, providing it a new-line character `\n`

```
console.log(locations.join("\n"));
```

Answer (score 1):

> use join function to remove comma

```
<script>
var locations=['CA','CH','LA'];
alert(locations.join("\n"));   
</script>
```

**Output**
[image]